# php combining text on images more than once?

Tags: php

I am trying to print users personal data like name, email, phone number on screen, using separate images, rather than printing out in clear text on page, thus getting cache possibly by Google. Trying to print like below:

Name - image with name text created on fly
Email - image with email text created on fly
Phoneno - image with number text created on fly

The code I have provided merges text into an image ie name, but only allows me to create one image to send back to browser, how can I try to get my script to send more than one image back to browser?

I have tried adding more parameters to my function function 'create_image($name,$email,$number)' but only prints one field to browser, perhaps something to do with header()?

```
<?php
//Send a generated image to the browser
$name="Bob";$email="bob@email.co.uk";$number="12345678901";
create_image($name);

function create_image($value)
{

    //Set the image width and height
    $width = 250;
    $height = 20; 

    //Create the image resource 
    $image = ImageCreate($width, $height);  

    //We are making three colors, white, black and gray
    $white = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    $black = ImageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
    $grey = ImageColorAllocate($image, 204, 204, 204);

    //Make the background black 
    ImageFill($image, 0, 0, $black); 

    //Add randomly generated string in white to the image
    //imagestring ( resource $image , int $font-(font size) , int $x-(from left) , int $y-(from right) , string $string , int $color-(font-colour) )
    ImageString($image, 5, 10, 3, $value, $white);

    //Tell the browser what kind of file is come in 
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); 

    //Output the newly created image in jpeg format 
    ImageJpeg($image);

    //Free up resources
    ImageDestroy($image);
}
?>
```

Thanks for any replies

Comment: one seperate php file for every image you want to show in your html code and then show the images like `<img src="name-img.php?someid=xxxx" />` for the name and `<img src="email-img.php?someid=xxxx" />` for the mail image

Comment: `ImageString($image, 5, 10, 3, $value, $white);` --- this line writes a `$value` obviously to the image. So with adding more function parameters you need to add more `ImageString`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$name="Bob";$email="bob@email.co.uk";$number="12345678901";
switch ($_GET['option']) {
    case 'name':
        create_image($name);
        break;
    case 'email':
        create_image($email);
        break;
    case 'number':
        create_image($number);
        break;
}
```

And call your script with `scriptname.php?option=name`

Answer (score 0):

its not really a best practice, but I i would try to change your function, that it saves the images to a file, and returns the file path, when theres is a valid file.
So you don't have to create every call a new image (which is slow), and you get a valid filepath, which means you don't have to care about headers and so on